# Repeated Ajax calls resolving Deferred differently, how?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jquery-deferred

I am curious if I am using the deferred incorrectly and if not - is there a more eloquent way.
So, I am firing this ajax request multiple times during a persons page view. Now, I understand I can only resolve the deffered once, so I reset the "def" appropriately. But I am wondering if I can assign the ajax call to the variable, and pass in the unique identifier and resolve the deferred?

I need things to happen either on the success or error of the ajax request.

So, I have an ajax request.

```
// some code. I set some var.

  var def = $.Deferred();

// more code

  $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: url,
        data: params,
        success: function(d) {
                     // resolve my deferred and pass a unique identifier
                        def.resolved('onSucc');
                 },
        error: function(d) {
                       def.resolved('onErr');
                    };

    });
```

To something like?

```
  var def = $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: url,
        data: params,
        success: function(d) {
                     // resolve my deferred and pass a unique identifier
                       return def.resolved('onSucc');
                 },
        error: function(d) {
                       return  def.resolved('onErr');
                    };

    });
```

Also, is there a need to return a promise here? My code seems to work ok without it - but I am curious if I am missing out.

Comment: From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) *"The jqXHR objects returned by $.ajax() as of jQuery 1.5 implement the Promise interface"*. Hence I'd argue it does not implement the deferred API and cannot be resolved with a custom value. The value is essentially a promise. Using your own deferred object seems totally fine by me.

Comment: Is there a reason to do this: def.resolved('whatever') vs. def.resolved('whatever').promise()?

Comment: What is the problem that you are trying to solve? Explain in terms of what your use case is. Avoid the [XY problem](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-does-xy-problem-mean) description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually not using deferred correctly. Deferred objects are for creating promise chains from scratch when [making a non-promisified API promisified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises). The way you're using it is called [the deferred anti pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns).

Promises chain, so instead of reverting to callbacks and deferred objects, you can simply use the chaining function `then` that transforms a promise into a new promise:

```
return $.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: url,
    data: params,
}).then(function(result){
     console.log("got result!", result);
     return someTransformOn(result); // use return values, can also return promise
}); // error case gets handled for you
```

Which would let you do:

```
functionReturningAjax().then(function(transformedValue){
    // access to transformed value here
},function(err){
   // then accepts an optional second argument for errors, use it to handle errors.
});
```

Comment: This looks good, but the reason I was using the deferred is because the method i need to call is in another module that I import.. SO, I need a hook. That hook was, I was hoping - the deferred.. like an "emitter".. basically, resolving it -- THUS enabling my function in another module to fire. Because in that module - I was using ".done( function(){ //do something})". So, if I didn't include the module.. no harm.. if i did, then it would be able to act upon the deferreds created in the parent module.

Comment: Benjamin - I accepted your answer, but I also asked another for a workaround for this anti-pattern: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23657518/is-there-a-way-to-trigger-call-a-method-in-another-module-that-might-exist

Comment: I added an answer to that too, see if it helps you