# Is there a way to trigger call a method in another module that "might" exist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I know this is a base question... but I'll try to explain.

I've been using a Deferred, but someone pointed out that I'm using it as an anti-pattern.
Basically, I can use the deferred in the child module. BUT if this is an anti-pattern, what is the best way to achieve this in which the "child module" might not be there.. SO, I don't want to explicitly call the child method in the success of the parent ajax call.

So, three questions:

1. Is this a viable way, if not - what is a good way to achieve what I am going for?
2. Even though I am resetting the Deferred, it isn't seeming to 'reset'. Why?
3. CAN this also be achieved coupling it with another event - ie, onload. SO< we have the ajax AND onload doing the same thing.

I have a parent module.

```
var Z = {};

Z.someVar = $.Deferred();

Z.a = function(){
    //methods

    //Ajax call on page: can be once or multiple calls.
    $AJAX = {
        url:...,
        dataType: ...,
        //etc..
    }.success(
      function(){
         Z.someVar.resolve();
      }
    ).error();


};

// another method that MIGHT exist.

Z.b = function(){
   var func1 = function(){
       // do some stuff
       Z.someVar = $.Deferred(); // reset it.
   }
   Z.someVar.done(function(){
      func1();
   })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A promise is an abstraction over a *single, one time* calculation of a value. A promise starts **pending**, and then can transition to either **fulfilled** or **rejected** state. Once a promise resolved (transitioned) it can never change its state again.

Deferreds are used in exactly one - when you want to construct a promise from something that's not a promise*.

In jQuery `$.ajax` already *returns* a promise to begin with.

```
Z.a = function(){ // this method now returns a promise
    return $.ajax({...});
};
```

If we want to chain it, we can use `.then` :

```
Z.a().then(function(){
    // here a() is done.
});
```

You can also use a caching pattern, using `$.when` (Promise.resolve in most promise libraries):

```
Z._a = null;
Z.a = function(){
    if(z._a){ // already have the value cached:
        return $.when(z._a); // promise over the value
    }
    return $.ajax({...}).then(function(res){
        Z._a = res;
        return res; // chain
    });

};

Z.b = function(){
    return Z.a().then(function(aValue){
        // do something with value, your return value here is the resolution
        // value of the a method call.
    });
}
```

Now, if you want to wait for multiple calls, you can use `$.when` with multiple promises and get their results.

<sup>There are other, very rare use cases with aggregation</sup>

Comment: THanks Benjamin, I appreciate your time in answering my questions. One additional one - is there a way to also incorporate a firing in another event outside of AJAX.. for example, onload etc.. Basically, the promise from the ajax AND some other event. How can one possibly couple both behaviors to perform the same..ie, call a method in another module?

Comment: @user1492442 `$.when(firstPromise,secondPromise).then(function(){...` - this waits for multiple promises to finish first.

Comment: OP seems to use the ("resettable") deferred for emitting events. In his original code, `.a()` is not called from `b()`, but from somewhere else - uncoupling them to some degree. It seems that promises might not be the solution to his problem.

Comment: @Bergi if the event is one time. I think it's a perfectly acceptable solution. I agree that his actual _goal_ needs to be clearer though.

Comment: Your caching is a little complicated, and doesn't work for falsy `res` values. Why not simplify to `function(){ return Z._a || (Z._a = $.ajax({…})); }`?

Comment: Hmmm, usually I don't like keeping returning the same promise since I usually work outside of jQuery promises when I can (they're not very good at throw safety or order of execution), however in this case, you can simplify to `return Z._a || (Z.__a = $.ajax({.. };` indeed.

Comment: Thank you for checking in.. for now, I went with what i had as to refactor the code, I need a little bit of time. I will update in the coming days. As Bergi surmises, I am using it as a "one off" of sorts.. actually, I use the ".resolve()" when my ajax errors OR when I load the page. So, each time, I reset the var a = $.Deferred(); Bergi is right, I am not actually needing the promise, only using it (the resolve) for sort of an emitter.